# Bootstrap carousel not pausing when using touchpad

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

I am using the bootstrap carousel:

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
    $('.carousel').carousel('pause');

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

I pause it from the beginning, so that I can just use the slide-function when clicking on the buttons:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="carousel-tab active"><a href="#">ListOne</a></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="carousel-tab"><a href="#">ListTwo</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="carousel-content">

                <div id="listOne" class="list-group"></div>

            </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="carousel-content">

                <div id="listTwo" class="list-group"></div>

            </div> 
        </div><!-- End Item -->

      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->

    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
```

This works fine. But the crazy thing is, that the moment I use my page on my laptop with touch functions on the screen and press the button with my finger and NOT with the mouse, the carousel ist not 'paused' anymore. Does anyone know why this is happening? This is very confusing for me.